# React Native Jest doesnt exit, and show the actual library as the cause of the problem

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest, react-native-testing-library

Im implementing tests framework (jest) in react native with testing-library/react-native, on an existing project.
When I run their example (intro) the app give the infamous error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
```

when I try to check it with the flag --detectOpenHandles, it shows that the library itself is the problem.
[image]

I have no config file for jest.
RN - 66.4
jest - 28.1.0
babel-jest - 26.6.3
jest-circus - 26.6.3
eslint-plugin-jest - 26.1.1

Comment: Did you try this? https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/20/how-to-fix-the-jest-did-not-exit-one-second-after-the-test-run-has-completed-error-with-typescript/

Comment: It appears that article is talking about closing a database connection to mongodb after running tests. In my case, like the op, there's no database connection in my app. It appears that simply running jest using react native testing library requires some sort of unknown cleanup

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by this code:

```
beforeAll(done => {
  done()
})

afterAll(done => {
  // Closing the DB connection allows Jest to exit successfully.
  mongoose.connection.close()
  done()
})
```

Comment: It appears that article is talking about closing a database connection to mongodb after running tests. In my case, like the op, there's no database connection in my app. It appears that simply running jest using react native testing library requires some sort of unknown cleanup